# Once, at once and when

Tags: grammar

Which one of the following is correct?

1. I will let you know **once** I have the information about it.
2. I will let you know **at once** I have the information about it.
3. I will let you know **at once when** I have the information about it.

Comment: "Once" means "when". "At once" means "immediately". "At once when" means "immediately when". All 3 sentences have slightly different meanings.

Comment: @NVZ except that No. 2 doesn't have a conjunction to link the two clauses. It could make sense, but it doesn't sound natural.

Comment: I'd say that 3 is the one that appears wrong, but arguably could make sense (with a comma after "at once" perhaps), while 2 is just totally wrong.

Answer (score 4):

### Correct sentence

The first one is the proper one to use:

> I will let you know **once** I have the information about it.

With the same meaning, you could simply say:

> I will let you know **when** I have the information about it.

### At once

At once is used to mean a few things.

> Bring me these files **at once** !
>
> Bring me these files **immediately** !

Or:

> I can't possibly do all those things **at once** !
>
> I can't possibly do all those things **at the same time** !

### Edit

As Rathony stated, the third one, **I will let you know at once when I have the information about it.** isn't strictly wrong and could mean "immediately when". But in this case, a more natural way to say it, to me, is:

> I will let you know **as soon as** I have the information about it.

Comment: I don't think No. 3 is wrong.

Comment: You're somewhat right. Though while not being strictly incorrect, I would definitely not say it, and prefer **I will let you know as soon as I have the information about it.** which sounds more natural.